# how to remove shadow from a WidgetControl?

Tags: python, leaflet, widget, ipyleaflet

Using the following code from `ipyleaflet` documentation I get a nice display with 2 extra custom widgets. These widgets have a small dark shadow that I would like to remove.

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, WidgetControl
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, ColorPicker, jslink

m = Map(center=(46.01, 6.16), zoom=12, basemap=basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter)
zoom_slider = IntSlider(description='Zoom level:', min=0, max=15, value=7)
jslink((zoom_slider, 'value'), (m, 'zoom'))
widget_control1 = WidgetControl(widget=zoom_slider, position='topright')
m.add_control(widget_control1)

color_picker = ColorPicker(description='Pick a color:')
widget_control2 = WidgetControl(widget=color_picker, position='bottomright')
m.add_control(widget_control2)
m
```

It's is useless as I'm using the dark theme from jupyterlab (which transforms the shadow in a horrible white shadow) as shown here:

[image]

I didn't find any parameter in the [documentation](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/widget_control.html), is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

digging in the `ipyleaflet` code, it seems that the shadow is mandatory as it's only set in this [css file](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/stable/js/src/jupyter-leaflet.css). The different options are set in the [js file](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/5d2ec2943f985014e413cf7a90122ca37b68b721/js/src/controls/WidgetControl.js#L128) meaning that shadow cannot be removed from python code.

As an ugly fix I forced some css directly on the top cell before import `ipyleaflet`:

```py
# ugly fix to remove shadow from map custom widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.leaflet-widgetcontrol {box-shadow: none}</style>"))
```